# Redirect to correct store view by customer browser language

Tags: redirect, store-view, magento2.1.6

I've added this code to the `index.php`:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang) {
    case "it":
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['first'] = "si";
        $params = $_SERVER;
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] 
        = 'italian'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] 
        = 'store'; 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
        $bootstrap->run($app); 
        break;     
    default: 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
        $bootstrap->run($app);
    break; 
}
```

This code detects and redirects properly but whenever I try to switch
to English storeview it redirects back to Italian. So, I need
something that redirects only on first time page loading.

I've tried to use sessions with object manager but it gives the following error:

> Object manager not initialized

Comment: The code you have posted is badly broken. You have a `$` on one line and `params` on the next. Similarly, you have a couple of `->` operators split onto separate lines. Surely, this is not your real code?

Comment: It is incorrectly formatted in this question but on php file there aren't mistakes like that, I've asked for adding something to code that allow to redirect only on first time page loading. Anyway thank you for answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You should always (or as far as possible) copy/paste the exact code you're using to avoid confusion. I have suggested an edit to fix the worst formatting problems for you.